# Unhandled exception at 0x61e1f5cf (msvcr90d.dll) in start.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c

## include "stdafx.h"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_ET_TABLES 10

typedef struct{
    unsigned char  ucVersion;
    unsigned char enMonitor;
    unsigned short uPid;
}SData_t;
typedef struct{
    unsigned char ucVersion;
    unsigned short uID;
    unsigned int uiCollected;
    SData_t st[MAX_ET_TABLES];
}STData_t; 

typedef struct{
   STData_t stData;   
}psTask;

psTask *pstTask;

int main()
{
    printf("\npstTask->stData = %u\n",&pstTask->stData);
    memset(&(pstTask->stData), 0xFF, sizeof(pstTask->stData)); 
    return 0;
}
```

I need to set the values for the structure variables as 0xFF.

The above program is throwing an unhandled exception as "Unhandled exception at
0x61e1f5cf (msvcr90d.dll) in start.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
0x00000000." please help me understand why it is.

```
      page    ,132
        title   memset - set sections of memory all to one byte
;***
;memset.asm - set a section of memory to all one byte
;
;       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
;
;Purpose:
;       contains the memset() routine
;
;*******************************************************************************

        .xlist
        include cruntime.inc
        .list

page
;***
;char *memset(dst, value, count) - sets "count" bytes at "dst" to "value"
;
;Purpose:
;       Sets the first "count" bytes of the memory starting
;       at "dst" to the character value "value".
;
;       Algorithm:
;       char *
;       memset (dst, value, count)
;               char *dst;
;               char value;
;               unsigned int count;
;               {
;               char *start = dst;
;
;               while (count--)
;                       *dst++ = value;
;               return(start);
;               }
;
;Entry:
;       char *dst - pointer to memory to fill with value
;       char value - value to put in dst bytes
;       int count - number of bytes of dst to fill
;
;Exit:
;       returns dst, with filled bytes
;
;Uses:
;
;Exceptions:
;
;*******************************************************************************

        CODESEG

    extrn   _VEC_memzero:near
    extrn   __sse2_available:dword

        public  memset
memset proc \
        dst:ptr byte, \
        value:byte, \
        count:dword

        OPTION PROLOGUE:NONE, EPILOGUE:NONE

        .FPO    ( 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 )

        mov     edx,[esp + 0ch] ; edx = "count"
        mov     ecx,[esp + 4]   ; ecx points to "dst"

        test    edx,edx         ; 0?
        jz      short toend     ; if so, nothing to do

        xor     eax,eax
        mov     al,[esp + 8]    ; the byte "value" to be stored

; Special case large block zeroing using SSE2 support
    test    al,al ; memset using zero initializer?
    jne     dword_align
    cmp     edx,0100h ; block size exceeds size threshold?
    jb      dword_align
    cmp     DWORD PTR __sse2_available,0 ; SSE2 supported?
    je      dword_align

    jmp     _VEC_memzero ; use fast zero SSE2 implementation
    ; no return

; Align address on dword boundary
dword_align:

        push    edi             ; preserve edi
        mov     edi,ecx         ; edi = dest pointer

        cmp     edx,4           ; if it's less then 4 bytes
        jb      tail            ; tail needs edi and edx to be initialized

        neg     ecx
        and     ecx,3           ; ecx = # bytes before dword boundary
        jz      short dwords    ; jump if address already aligned

        sub     edx,ecx         ; edx = adjusted count (for later)
adjust_loop:
        mov     [edi],al
        add     edi,1
        sub     ecx,1
        jnz     adjust_loop

dwords:
; set all 4 bytes of eax to [value]
        mov     ecx,eax         ; ecx=0/0/0/value
        shl     eax,8           ; eax=0/0/value/0

        add     eax,ecx         ; eax=0/0val/val

        mov     ecx,eax         ; ecx=0/0/val/val

        shl     eax,10h         ; eax=val/val/0/0

        add     eax,ecx         ; eax = all 4 bytes = [value]

; Set dword-sized blocks
        mov     ecx,edx         ; move original count to ecx
        and     edx,3           ; prepare in edx byte count (for tail loop)
        shr     ecx,2           ; adjust ecx to be dword count
        jz      tail            ; jump if it was less then 4 bytes

>         rep     stosd         // the arrow comes here when that exception is thrown

main_loop_tail:
        test    edx,edx         ; if there is no tail bytes,
        jz      finish          ; we finish, and it's time to leave
; Set remaining bytes

tail:
        mov     [edi],al        ; set remaining bytes
        add     edi,1

        sub     edx,1           ; if there is some more bytes
        jnz     tail            ; continue to fill them

; Done
finish:
        mov     eax,[esp + 8]   ; return dest pointer
        pop     edi             ; restore edi

        ret

toend:
        mov     eax,[esp + 4]   ; return dest pointer

        ret

memset  endp

        end
```

> EDITED:

```
int main()
{
    psTask *pstTask;
    pstTask = (psTask*)malloc(sizeof(psTask));
    pstTask = NULL;
    printf("\npstTask->stData = %u\n",&pstTask->stData);
    memset(&(pstTask->stData), 0xFF, sizeof(pstTask->stData)); 
    return 0;
}
```

I tried like this bu still getting the exception.Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Since `pstTask` is a global variable, this line:

```
psTask *pstTask;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
psTask *pstTask = 0x00000000;
```

and since you never later change it to point anywhere else (e.g., to properly allocated memory), this line:

```
    memset(&(pstTask->stData), 0xFF, sizeof(pstTask->stData));
```

is equivalent to this:

```
    memset(0x00000000, 0xFF, sizeof(pstTask->stData));
```

(since `stData` is the first element of the `psTask` structure, so has an offset of zero). This means that you're trying to write `0xFF` into memory location `0x00000000` (as well as the subsequent 47 bytes or so), rather than to memory that you actually have permission to write to (e.g. stack space, or space returned by `malloc`).

---

**Update** for updated question:

This bit:

```
    pstTask = (psTask*)malloc(sizeof(psTask));
    pstTask = NULL;
```

allocates memory for a `psTask` and points `pstTask` at it — so far so good — but then it sets `pstTask` right back to `NULL` (i.e., not pointing anywhere valid). You need to remove that second line.

Also, after calling `malloc` you should always examine its return value; if it returns `NULL`, that means you're out of memory. So, you should write something like this:

```
    pstTask = (psTask*)malloc(sizeof(psTask));
    if(pstTask == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\npstTask->stData = %u\n",&pstTask->stData);
```

(In this specific case, I'm sure that `malloc` will successfully return allocated memory, but you should really *always* check its return value.)

Comment: @ruakh : thank you for explainiing me clearly. I have done some modifications but still i'm getting the exception dude.

Comment: The first equivalence is true in general only because `0x00000000` is a null pointer constant.  It stores a null pointer value in `pstTask`, which is not *necessarily* all-bits-zero (though as it happens it is on Windows, which apparently is the environment in which the program is running).  I find it clearer to think of it in terms of null pointers rather than `0x00000000`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, yes. I chose `0x00000000` as my null-pointer notation because that's what was in the OP's error-message. I suppose I should have explicitly used the phrase "null pointer" somewhere in my answer, but it didn't seem essential, because the problem was really that `pstTask` wasn't pointing anywhere, rather than specifically that it was null. (And if you're going to complain about a potential false implication that the null pointer is necessarily all-bits-zero, then why not complain about a potential false implication that a pointer is necessarily 32 bits long?)

Comment: @Angus: About an hour after your last comment, you accepted my answer. Does that mean that you figured out the problem, or do you still need help with this? (In the latter case, you should de-accept my answer, because as it is right now, people will think you no longer need help.)

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks for helping me to understand dude. Thanks. I will try that and let u know.